# Run Add-in from PrebuildEvent

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, pre-build-event

I'm writing an VS 2008 add-in to synchronize Setup project Version with startup project assembly version. It works fine.
But I was wondering if it was possible to call add-in from the Pre-build Event of my setup project. 
It works fine by command line window, but I didn't find any syntax to make it work in Pre-build Event. Is Someone has an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just type the DOS command line to call your utility in the Pre -build event. There is a number of macros supported by msbuild to help you access the dll, settings, etc.

If it gets really involved, you might want to build your own TaskItem - there you will have full control over the situation